# Howto call a Function from another class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'd like to call the method refreshMe () from the home.ts. But I get the message that it is not in the typeof.

Here is what i've tried: 
=> settings.ts

```
import { HomePage } from '../home/home'
```

[...]

```
HomePage.refreshMe();
```

=> home.ts

```
refreshMe() {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
    }
```

Here again the exact error message:

> Property 'refreshMe' does not exist on type 'typeof HomePage'.

Comment: it may not be really DRY, but if the method is just one line, you should add that as a method in the component where you wan to call it. Injecting a page in another page may cause some issues later...

Comment: I see, how can i do this ? Im new to Ionic, can you maybe give me some example code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a Page from another class with Ionic3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901083/how-to-reload-a-page-from-another-class-with-ionic3)

Comment: If it's ok for you, could you please delete this question since it's a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901083/how-to-reload-a-page-from-another-class-with-ionic3/44901255#44901255)? Or is it somehow different? Thanks :)

Comment: Sry i'm not allowed to delete this. But yeah i guess its pretty the same.

Comment: Really? AFAIK you should be allowed to delete it since you're the owner of the question...

Comment: If you make method static you can use HomePage.refreshMe(). Otherwise you'd need an object instance - ie something like this.refreshMe().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Try something like this,

create a provider with ionic cli using the command,

```
ionic g provider providerName
```

now put your refreshMe() function inside the provider so that you can import the provider and use the refreshMe function wherever you want like this

```
import { NewProvider } from '../home/home'

constructor(public myProvider: NewProvider ){
   myProvider.refreshMe();
}
```

Comment: I guess it worked. But now i cant load the Settingspage. The ony thing i get was this useless error: '[INFO:CONSOLE(1436)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1436)'

Comment: terminate it and run it again with ionic serve

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for HomePage!
injectionError@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1583:86
noProviderError@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1621:12
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._throwOrNull@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3122:19
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3161:20
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3093:20
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:2962:16

Comment: in your app.module.ts add "HomePage" under "providers:"

Comment: Here are my providers: providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    HomePage,
    File,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ] .. I still got the Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NavController!
injectionError@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1583:86
noProviderError@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1621:12
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._throwOrNull@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3122:19
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3161:20

Comment: this is not the right way to do this I guess. I have updated the answer. check it and try something like that

Comment: The thing is i need to refresh the HomePage. A new Provider is useless for me :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148285/discussion-between-gowtham-and-mrflyingtoasterman).