# How to reload a Page from another class with Ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have 2 Folders. `/HomePage` and `/SettingsPage`.

`/HomePage` contains:

- home.html
- home.ts

The `/SettingsPage` contains:

- settings.html
- settings.ts

I want to "clean"/reload my `HompePage` (`home.html`) from `settings.ts`

I reload/refresh my `settings.html` with this:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) for that:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// SettingsPage (publish an event when you need to reload the HomePage)
constructor(public events: Events) {}

shouldReload() {
  events.publish('shouldReloadData');
}


// HomePage (listen for the event to reload the page)
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('shouldReloadData', () => {
    // Reload the page here
  });
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thats exactly what i need! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)